# Find value of input, by known data attribute? - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two separate forms and input fields, with a data attribute. When an action is performed on one of them (in this case, when he clicks the input field), I want to gather the value of the other.

I already have a code to get the data attribute of the field the user is working in, here:

```
$(document).on("click", ".answerinputcss",function() {
    var singleAnswerInteger = ($(this).data('integer-answer'));
    var singleAnswerText = ($(this).val());
});
```

And because I have that, I know what integer will be used by the mate field (if integer-answer is 901, then the other input will also be 901.)

Thus, the second field is an `input` type, with an attribute named `data-integer-question`, which also has the value of `901`. What do I add to my code, to get its value as a variable?

Comment: Whats the selector for the other input?? Just give it an id

Comment: @KyleK I was hoping I could do it by the data attribute, to reduce code -  but alright. :)

Comment: I misundertsood your question completely....have a look at my new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select by the data-attribute  *[data-attribute="#"]

```
$(document).on("click", ".answerinputcss",function() {
   var singleAnswerInteger =  $(this).data('integer-answer');
   var singleAnswerText = ($(this).val());
   var secondAnswerText = $('*[data-integer-question="'+singleAnswerInteger+'"]').val();
});
```